# How can I make a curve in this axe blade?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

How can I do that curve in the axe and the edge part too? I'm having some trouble with the warp tool, and another question

[image]

As you can see the handle is apart from the edge so, the question is how I make a exactly hole in the same shape of the handle ? what can I use for this ?

I was thinking about boolean, but I don't know if I apply a boolean to a object, the same object when it comes to render the image will show the boolean applied or not.

There's is any good way to do this without overlapping objects that can cause some problems in the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some more geometry.

Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> -> *Subdivide* with a number of cuts.

[image]

Then you can select some verts and use *Proportional Editing* (Shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>) to shape the head in many ways.

[image]

Here's spherical falloff for example.  In general, proportional editing will be very helpful for stuff like this.

Comment: This worked incredibly well ! I made the axe with the curves. After i got the hang using the proportional editing is very handy, great for organic shapes too. Thanks for the Help o/